# How can I move over from local with node js to on my vps?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

rn I'm using vs code live server @ :5500 to access the site with localhost:3000 for the server part of the code

https://github.com/AlgNinja/NodeChatApp thats the code

How would I move it over to my vps

I got the repository on it

But what in the code would I have to change to make it work properly

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is where you define the port for the application:
https://github.com/AlgNinja/NodeChatApp/blob/master/server.js#L1

You can change this to port 80 (so that it works in most firewalls) and connect VPS_IP:80 from your client.

To start the app you need to run the following command:
`node server.js` on the VPS, which should start your server.

I hope this is for testing and you are not planning to put this into production :)